# minikube dashboard not working

Tags: ubuntu, docker, minikube

I'm pretty new with Minikube.
I want to try minikube in a local machine.
I installed ubuntu server and docker.
I've downloaded and started minikube using this command:

> sudo minikube start --vm-driver=none

If I type this command:

> sudo kubectl get services --all-namespaces

if I type: **sudo minikube dashboard --url** I get: **http://127.0.0.1:30000**

If I try to use the browser installed on my laptop (replacing 127.0.0.1 with the server ip address) I cannot connect to the  Minikube dashboard.

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

simply type '`minikube dashboard`' from command terminal.

Comment: If you ran minikube as root user, you might run into problems opening the browser from the cli. For these cases simply get the url of the dashboard and paste it to the browser manually: `minikube dashboard --url`

Comment: I got below output when I ran the command you specified.

```bash
P51713:~ user$ minikube dashboard
Waiting, endpoint for service is not ready yet...
Waiting, endpoint for service is not ready yet...
...
Waiting, endpoint for service is not ready yet...
Waiting, endpoint for service is not ready yet...
Could not find finalized endpoint being pointed to by kubernetes-dashboard: Temporary Error: No endpoints for service are ready yet
...
Temporary Error: No endpoints for service are ready yet
Temporary Error: No endpoints for service are ready yet
```

Answer (score 7):

I think you have to enable it.
check if the addon is enabled first:

```
 minikube addons list
```

If it´s disabled then:

```
 minikube addons enable dashboard
```

then you can get the url typing:

```
 minikube dashboard --url
```

Answer (score 2):

I had problem when tried to launch dashboard with command `minikube dashboard` i recived:

```
  Enabling dashboard ...
  Verifying dashboard health ...
  Launching proxy ...
  Verifying proxy health ...
```

And nothing happens...

Then checked system pods like `kubectl get pod -n kube-system` and recived:

```
kube-proxy-4h255                   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   6          10m
```

Then tried to check what happens `kubectl logs  kube-proxy-4h255 -n kube-system` and recivedn:

```
I1006 09:56:08.110470       1 server.go:650] Version: v1.20.2
I1006 09:56:08.111489       1 conntrack.go:100] Set sysctl 'net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_max' to 131072
F1006 09:56:08.111542       1 server.go:495] open /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_max: permission denied
```

To **solve** this, set parameter like `sudo sysctl net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_max=131072`
as written [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind/issues/2240)

Answer (score 1):

You can access port 30000 from localhost, not from other hosts. Check it locally by `curl -v http://127.0.0.1:30000`

As workaround use ssh-tunnel to access this port like from localhost or add/modify k8s service for type **nodePort** or use k8s ingress.

Check you firewall rules (disable it) and check dashboard pod (`kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide`).

Answer (score 1):

If I am not understand wrong, you installed Ubuntu vm and install minikube with none driver inside Ubuntu vm?

If this is case, the dashboard localhost:30000 is inside ubuntu, so it won't work to access it from your laptop host.

You need to access it from Ubuntu web browser if it is desktop version or setup port forward:

127.0.0.1:30000 to guest 30000

then you can access to 127.0.0.2:30000 from your laptop.

Answer (score 1):

After starts your minikube, check the status of your cluster with

```
$ kubectl cluster-info
```

If you have anything referencing a "localhost" address for example, delete the instance and starts again

```
$ minikube delete
```

and reapply your start (I prefer to use local rather than use virtual box as driver)

```
$ minikube start --vm-driver = virtualbox
```

when trying to get info from your cluster you will have described

```
$ Kubernetes master is running at https: // <ip>: 8443
```

will mean success, after that in a simple way as said previously execute

```
$ minikube dashboard
```

which will redirect you to dashboard page

Answer (score 0):

- Use the latest release of kubectl and minikube  reinstall by curl.
- I use  docker on my Mac and use the brew installed the minikube the version    `minikube 1.20.0_1 already installed` and got this [bug](https://github.com/rancher/k3d/issues/612) and **it's fix at** [v1.23.0](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/pull/11957/commits/746d5d14b1e5907f7642c96ef429655f7900c22f) .

> Skip setting "net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established"    tcpEstablishedTimeout: 0s
> Skip setting "net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close"    tcpCloseWaitTimeout: 0s